# Let $\mu_n$ be a sequence of finite measures on space $(X,M)$ and $\forall E \in M, \lim_{n \to \infty }\mu_n(E)=\mu(E)< \infty $..

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu_n$ be a sequence of finite measures on space $(X,M),M-\text{ sigma algebra on X}$ and $\forall E \in M, \lim_{n \to \infty }\mu_n(E)=\mu(E)< \infty $ and let $f$ be a bounded function.
Prove: 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty }\int_{E}fd\mu_{n}=\int_{E}fd\mu$$

The idea is to first prove this for simple functions, then positive and lastly for arbitrary functions that satisfy the question. For simple functions it is quite clear. I am interested how would I go about proving for the other two types of functions.

Comment: Given a bounded function $f$, you can approximate it uniformly (in $L^\infty$ norm ) with a simple function. $$\|f - \sum c_i \chi_{\{f^{-1} (c_i)\}}\|_\infty \leq \epsilon$$ for finitely many $c_i$'s (cut up the image of $f$, which is contained in $[-M, M]$) . And you can switch the between uniform limit and integral.

Comment: Are you not assuming that $f$ is measurable?

Comment: @Xiao "And you can switch the between uniform limit and integral." How is this done? You don't mention, the sequence of measures, can you give more detail on your insight, if it's not a problem in an answer?

Comment: @BozoVulicevic what I stated was a general result that might be useful. For the switching between uniform limit and integral, you can find this in many classic real analysis text, it is a result for Riemann Integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $f$ is bounded and measurable, since $|f|\leq M$ a.e. define the simple function
$$g(x):=\sum c_i \chi_{\{f^{-1}(c_i)\}}(x)$$
 where $c_i \in [-M, M]$ and $\cup_i (c_i-\epsilon/2, c_i+\epsilon/2) \supset [-M, M]$, we have $\|f - g\|_\infty \leq \epsilon$.

Now 
$$\limsup_n \bigg|\int_X f d\mu_n -\int_X f d\mu \bigg| \\
\leq  \limsup_n \bigg|\int_X f d\mu_n -\int_X g d\mu_n\bigg| + \bigg|\int_X g d\mu - \int_X f d\mu \bigg|  \\
\leq \epsilon \lim_n \mu_n (X) + \epsilon \mu(X)$$

Answer (score 2):

Because $f$ is bounded, we may suppose without loss of generality that $0\le f(x)\le 1$ for all $x\in X$. In this case $\int_E f\,d\mu_n=\int_0^1\mu_n(E\cap \{x:f(x)>t\})\,dt$ (and likewise for $\int_E f\,d\mu$)). As $n\to\infty$ the integrand $\mu_n(E\cap \{x:f(x)>t\})$ converges to $\mu(E\cap \{x:f(x)>t\})$ for each $t\in[0,1]$. The integrand is moreover bounded above by $\mu_n(E)$, and $\sup_n\mu_n(E)<\infty$ because $\lim_n\mu_n(E)$ exists. It follows that $\lim_n\int_E f\,d\mu_n=\int_E f\,d\mu$ by the Bounded Convergence Theorem.